# Identify objects with repeated measures, and with the same ID between years

Tags: r, classification, repeat, difference

I would like to reclassify the names of some individuals in a dataframe with consequtive letters, and the reclassification criterion has to change each X intervals since the first occurrence of an individual. I explain it better with an example.

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, 8, 12, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 21, 22, 19 )
Year <- c (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
df <- data.frame (ID, Year)
df
```

I have a dataset with repeated measures of some individuals along 6 years. As you can see some `IDs` like the `"1" or "8"` are repeated in `Year == 1,2,3,4,5` for the `ID == 1` and `Year == 2,4` for the `ID == 8`. However different individuals may have the same `ID` if some time has happened since the first occurrence of an individual. It is because we consider that the individual dies each 2 years, and the `ID` may be reused.

In this hypothetical case, we assume that the life of an individual is 2 years, and that we can recognise during the sampling different individuals perfectly. The `ID == 1` in the `Year == 1` and `Year == 2` represent the same individual, however the `ID == 1` in the `Year == 1,2`, `Year == 3,4` and `Year == 5` represent different individuals. It is because the individual with `ID == 1` from the `Year == 1` couldn't live that long. The problem is that the first occurrence of the individuals may happen in different years and repeatedly as in this case. So the code has to forget an `ID` each 2 years since its first occurrence, and classify a new occurrence as a new individual.

I would like to name each individual with an unique `ID`. The new name does not have to be arranged chronologically as you can see with the `ID == 1` in the `Year == 5`. I only want that they will be named with an unique name.

Below I have put the expected result.

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, 8, 12, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 21, 22, 19 )
Year <- c (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 6, 6)
new_ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "M", "N", "Q", "S", "L", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "CC", "AA", "BB", "Y")
new_df <- data.frame (ID, Year, new_ID)
new_df
```

As you can see the `ID == 1` have different `new_ID` in the `Year == 1` `Year == 4` and `Year == 5`, because we assume that if one individual occurs for the first time in the `Year == 1`, an individual with the same ID in the `Year == 3` is different, and the same with the individual that occurs in the `Year == 5`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the final output, did you intend to have `Year == 1` at row 34?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` and `cut`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
       mutate(x = as.numeric(cut(Year, seq(min(Year)-1, max(Year)+1, 2))),
              idout = paste0(ID, ".", x))

   ID Year x idout
1   1    1 1   1.1
2   2    1 1   2.1
3   3    1 1   3.1
4   4    1 1   4.1
5   5    1 1   5.1
6   6    1 1   6.1
7   7    1 1   7.1
8   1    2 1   1.1
9   2    2 1   2.1
10  3    2 1   3.1
11  8    2 1   8.1
12  9    2 1   9.1
13 10    2 1  10.1
14 11    2 1  11.1
15 12    2 1  12.1
16  1    3 2   1.2
17  2    3 2   2.2
18  3    3 2   3.2
19  4    3 2   4.2
20  5    3 2   5.2
21  6    3 2   6.2
22  1    4 2   1.2
23  2    4 2   2.2
24  6    4 2   6.2
25  8    4 2   8.2
26 12    4 2  12.2
27  7    5 3   7.3
28 15    5 1  15.1
29 16    5 1  16.1
30 17    5 1  17.1
31 18    5 1  18.1
32 19    5 1  19.1
33 20    5 1  20.1
34  1    5 3   1.3
35 21    6 1  21.1
36 22    6 1  22.1
37 19    6 1  19.1
```

NB there are two mismatches with your desired output: row 34, and 15,26 where you have an L at years 2 and 4 with the same ID. I think these are mistakes?

Comment: How can I change the time intervals to consider individuals with the same ID as different individuals? I have tried the last number of the `mutate` code, the `2`, but it doesn't work. E.g. with this dataset `ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11) 
Year <- c (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50) df <- data.frame(ID, Year)` However I get the error `Error in cut.default(1, seq(min(1) - 1, max(1) + 1, 15)) : 
  invalid number of intervals` How can I change the time variation? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, 8, 12, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 21, 22, 19 )
Year <- c (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
new_ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "M", "N", "Q", "S", "L", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "CC", "AA", "BB", "Y")
new_df <- data.frame (ID, Year, new_ID)
new_df
# if all ID renews same use:
newID<-sapply(unique(ID), function(x) c(0,cumsum(diff(Year[ID==x]))%%2))
# if some ID renews different year use:
newID<-sapply(unique(ID), function(x) {
  mod<-2
  if(x==1) mod <- 3
  c(0,cumsum(diff(Year[ID==x]))%%mod)
 })
names(newID)<-(unique(ID))

new_df<-data.frame(ID,Year,IDcond=NA,new_ID=NA)
for(i in unique(ID)){
  new_df[new_df[,1]==i,3]<-newID[[which(unique(ID)==i)]]
}

ltrs<-c(LETTERS,apply(combn(LETTERS,2,simplify = T),2,function(x) paste(x,sep = "",collapse = "")))

ltrn<-0
for(i in 1:nrow(new_df)){
  if(new_df[i,3]==0) {ltrn<-ltrn+1;new_df[i,4]<-ltrs[ltrn]}
  else {ind<-which(new_df[,1]==new_df[i,1])
        ind<-ind[ind<i]
        new_df[i,4]<-tail(new_df[ind,4],1)}
}

new_df

> new_df
   ID Year IDcond new_ID
1   1    1      0      A
2   2    1      0      B
3   3    1      0      C
4   4    1      0      D
5   5    1      0      E
6   6    1      0      F
7   7    1      0      G
8   1    2      1      A
9   2    2      1      B
10  3    2      1      C
11  8    2      0      H
12  9    2      0      I
13 10    2      0      J
14 11    2      0      K
15 12    2      0      L
16  1    3      0      M
17  2    3      0      N
18  3    3      0      O
19  4    3      0      P
20  5    3      0      Q
21  6    3      0      R
22  1    4      1      M
23  2    4      1      N
24  6    4      1      R
25  8    4      0      S
26 12    4      0      T
27  7    5      0      U
28 15    5      0      V
29 16    5      0      W
30 17    5      0      X
31 18    5      0      Y
32 19    5      0      Z
33 20    5      0     AB
34  1    5      0     AC
35 21    6      0     AD
36 22    6      0     AE
37 19    6      1      Z
```

Comment: This code works well!! 
The unique problem is that it indicates an error in the line `new_df[new_df[,1]==i,2]<-tmp[[which(unique(ID)==i)]] `.
It says: "Error: object 'tmp' not found"

I don't know how it is affecting the whole. Could you tell me what you wanted to do with the object `tmp`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have compared the result of the code with the correct result making a `cbind` between my input and the output of your solution, and I have seen that some results don't match.
For example, with the `ID == 6` that appear in the `lines == 6, 21 and 24` and have the `Year == 1, 3 and 4` respectively. The `new_ID` for the `ID == 6` in the `Year == 4` should be the same than in the `Year ==3`, the `new_ID == R`, because there is only one year from the second appearance of the `ID==6`.  I have tried to solve the code changing `diff(Year[ID==x]))%%2` but I cannot solve it.
Could you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Now `new_ID` for `ID == 6` at `lines == 21 & 24` are the same which `new_ID = "R"`

Comment: I'm testing other datasets, and when I vary the variable `Year` the code doesn't work. e.g. 

`ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, 8, 12, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 21, 22, 19 )


Year <- c (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 200, 200, 200)


df <- data.frame(ID, Year)


df <- df[with(df, order(Year, ID)),]`

Do you know why? And If I would like to modify the condition from each 2 years to 48 years I have to modify the `%%2`?

Comment: @Ruben sorry for late response. I think you are right.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how start the count at any time that an individual is considered as new?

Comment: newID<-sapply(unique(ID), function(x) {
  mod<-2
  if(x==1) mod <- 3
  c(0,cumsum(diff(Year[ID==x]))%%mod)
  })

Comment: The code gives the next error: Error: unexpected 'if' in "newID<-sapply(unique(ID), function(x) { mod<-2 if"

Comment: I have added my comment on the answer. But if your year data for a specific ID is not increase one by one it will not work.

Comment: Firstly thanks, The year variable will increase one by one, but the individuals may appear in year 1 and 2, and later in year 256 and 257. 

I think that the code does'nt work exactly right. It's beceause in the row 16 the individual 1 should have a new ID because two years have passed since its first appearance in year 1. The code should detect that the maximum live of the individual 1 that appears in the year 1 is the year 2 like occurs with the individual 2 located in the row 17 that have a new ID. Moreover it doesn't work with the last dataset that I put above within our comments (19 Nov).

Comment: Yes. It does not work with your last dataset. Because i've written it for your first question.

Comment: But for the first does'nt work, the individual 1 is not well located in year 3